# EXSLT date:add function has unexpected results

Tags: date, xslt-1.0, exslt

I want to get tomorrows date using exslt date.

`date:date()` returns todays date ('2014-01-23') and if I am adding 1 day ('P1D'), I expect it to be tomorrow ('2014-01-24'). But instead the result of

```
<xsl:value-of select="date:add(date:date(), 'P1D')"/>
```

is '2014-01-23T23:00:00Z'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me some time of research but finally I solved the problem:

The problem with my previous implementation was caused by the **timezone**. The exact return value of `date:date()` is '2014-01-23+01:00' (a date with timezone; for me it's +01:00).

Adding a duration via `date:add(string, string)` seems to have a problem with that. So to get the correct result I just cut off the timezone from todays date. The result of

```
<xsl:value-of select="date:add(substring(date:date(), 1, 10), 'P1D')"/>
```

is tomorrows date ('2014-01-24') as expected.

Comment: how to add a second? what would be the duration value for that

Comment: @iRamesh Sorry for the late answer. To add a second it would be "PT1S". The used Syntax is the duration syntax specified in ISO 8601. The 'T' is the date-time delimiter. Before the delimiter it's Y = year, M = month, D = day and after the delimiter it's H = hour; M = minute; S = second. As you see, the 'T' is important to differ months from minutes.